# Django Database query works on local machine, but not on server

Tags: django, database, digital-ocean

This is the query:

`comment = AdditionalComment.objects.get(form = form, student = students[student])`

and works perfectly on my local machine.

Ive deployed the project to a DO VPS and whenever I try access the view i get this error even though I can see the AdditionalComment in the admin panel:

```
File "/home/smartsurvey/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/smartsurvey/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/smartsurvey/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/smartsurvey/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/smartsurvey/smart-survey/forms/views.py", line 195, in view_replies
    comment = AdditionalComment.objects.get(form = form, student = students[student])
  File "/home/smartsurvey/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/smartsurvey/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
forms.models.DoesNotExist: AdditionalComment matching query does not exist.`
```

Any idea what it could be? let me know if you need anymore info

Comment: there is no data in your server

Comment: @Exprator I can see the objects in the admin panel

Comment: then print students[student] and check whats it is returning and match if you have that data

Answer (score 0):

I realised I was querying the database for users comments before they had made them, so I added an if statement checking if they had replied.

Answer (score -1):

Error says: there is no AdditionalComment with such parameters. You need create AdditionalComment instance, and after you can get it.